# Is it possible to overload or change the copy and paste function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, clipboard, copy-paste

With the copy and paste function in Mango, is it possible to overload the behavior of the copy button when the text is selected ?

Example : the text is selected, the copy button shows up with (or is replaced by) an other button with a totally diferent behavior (find definition, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this is definitely not possible. Windows Phone 7 applications may use a relatively restrictive set of APIs. None of these allow you to change cross-application phoen functionality.